# Check if Chrome still supports Apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Is there a way to programatically check (e.g. via Chrome cmd line) whether Chrome still supports Chrome Apps?

**Background:** I am starting a Chrome App via a Linux script. Google has announced to remove support for Chrome Apps beginning of 2018 from Chrome. In case a new Chrome version would not support Apps anymore, I would have to notify the user to download the Electron version of the App. But therefore I need the information whether Chrome still supports Apps or not.

Comment: The way an app not supported error would be reported has not yet been decided/implemented.

Comment: I already feared that. Thanks!

Comment: Consider opening an issue on https://crbug.com or ask in [chrome apps announce](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-apps) group.